# How to store SharePoint survey responses to list using JSOM or Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to store the responses in survey list manually using JSOM or javascript Please Suggest me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This..

```
   var siteUrl ="";
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(surveyListName);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item(InternalNameofsurveyquestion, answerText);

    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function onQuerySucceeded() {
     alert("Success")
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }));
```